Why is phantom wallet not displaying tokens that Solscan say are in my wallet?
Just accessed phantom wallet and it's not displaying tokens that are still held in the wallet. Solscan and Ethscan both confirm that so I don't know what's going on with Phantom.

I have the same issues. All my memes have disappeared only Sol in my wallet

The coin was lost as well.
ผมเป็นคนไทยพิมภาษาอังกฤษก็ไม่เป็น

Update: the issue is now resolved.

We have just deployed a fix. The token balances should be back soon!

Original post: this was a bug in Phantom.

We are investigating the issue with token balances not loading. Please do not worry, our engineers are working to resolve this issue ASAP!!

